# Unable tp Switch the context for the third child iframe in the window

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My window has three iframes, I am able to switch to, the first two frames in the hierarchy and perform the actions, but unable to switch the context to the third frame.

[image: iframes]

I am able to switch to `FWin0` and `Content0` frame and set/get the values in the screen, but unable to switch the context to `content` iframe. I tried all the possible options.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("FWin0"); - Works fine
driver.switchTo().frame("Content0"); - Works fine
     driver.switchTo().frame("contnet"); - Fails, I tried integer options too
```

Comment: Try creating a webelemnt for the iframe using xpath and the div on top of the last iframe. The image div id is blurred. Can't see it. You can pass the webelement as an argument into switch method.

Comment: what error it is throwing? Any chance to share the webpage url you are trying?

Comment: What a peculiar way to create a HTML page, nested IFrames.

Comment: @Babai: No frame found expection displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide info on why you think it fails?

Meanwhile, try this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // switch out of all frames

List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("iframe"));
// print out the frames.size()

driver.switchTo().frame("FWin0");
driver.switchTo().frame("Content0");
frames = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("iframe"));
// print out the frames.size() again

// find frame element and switch to
WebElement contentFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#content"));
// alternative css locator: By.cssSelector("iframe[id='content']")
// alternative css locator: By.cssSelector("iframe[name='content']")
// alternative css locator: By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='customSearch']")
// alternative xpath locator: By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'customSearch')]")
driver.switchTo().frame(contentFrame);
```

Comment: I am using IE Webdriver, the script is unable to identify the third frame. When I tried your piece of code its throws an expection "NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == iframe[name='content']". Do we have limitation in switching between the frames using IE driver?

Comment: @Thirumalai: Answer updated. Please provide feedback as I can only guess what could be the issue. Is your site public?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The first solution worked out, I have tried with By.tag("iframe"). Can you please share your logic?

Comment: @Thirumalai: Oh well, I think you have done well, nothing wrong with your logic or anything. Just debug a lot and try out different locators, also I always find the frame element first, then pass the element into `driver.switchTo().frame`, instead of name or id (but in your case, name or id should work, not sure why it didn't).